# Can I have approve/deny wall postings on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Is there a way for me to moderate what comments get on my wall?  I'd like any comments posted to have to be approved or denied by me before they get posted.  So if I give the OK they go, otherwise they never show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that is not possible. There is the [option](http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy) to allow certain friend lists to comment. But you cannot moderate users to comment with approval/denial.

**Update**
Facebook has a [feature](https://www.facebook.com/about/control) coming soon for at least tagged posts.

[image: Facebook Control]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Facebook does now provide a setting to allow you to review posts before they appear on your Timeline (a.k.a Wall), go here to see the relevant available privacy settings:

https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=timeline&section=review&view

[image: Screenshot showing the Facebook privacy settings for who can post to your Timeline aka Wall]